# On relation between prime numbers and exponential Diophantine equation $c\cdot a^x\pm b=z$, feat. $71999999\cdots$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, exponential-diophantine-equations

While dealing with some integers which are the elements of the following set
$$\{p\mid p\in\mathbb{P}, p=72\times(10^n)-1\}$$

I've could observed that when $n\in\{6,7,8,9\}$, they are all primes.(Such as $71999999$ when $n=6$)

So I've come to wonder the following two questions.

1. It is hard to imagine that there exist a Diophantine equation $a^n\pm b=z$,
   that is $z\in \mathbb{P} $ for $\{n\mid 1\le n\leq \infty, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$.
   Can we prove this or would this be a conjecture? - (Edit: Clear, see the comment)
2. As I've shown above, I've dealt with the case $p=72\times(10^n)-1$, which has the sequence of consecutive primes for $n\in\{6,7,8,9\}$. Would there be any exponential Diophantine equation $a^n\pm b=z$ which has longer length of consecutive primes than I've observed? For example, if there is any exponential Diophantine equation $a^n\pm b=z$ that is prime for $n\in\{6,7,8,9,10\}$, then we can call that formula has some longer length of consecutive primes than the one I've observed with. Maybe we can compare them as $length (5) > length (4)$.
   I'm sure there should be some longer length for some equation than I've got. So if you know any of them, unless it is for some publication, I would like to ask you share the result on here answers so many site users can be shared with those results.

Thanks.

Comment: If, say, $a-b=p$, for some prime $p$, then $a^p\equiv b\pmod p$.

Comment: If $a^n+b=p$ is prime, then $p\mid a^{n+k(p-1)}+b$ for any $k\geq0.$ So one prime gives infinitely many non-primes. (No reason to use $\pm$ here, just say $b\in\mathbb Z$.)

Comment: In particular, $72\cdot 10^{71999999+6}-1$ is not prime.

Comment: And this is not a Diophantine equation. At best, it is an “exponential Diophantine equation,” but it is really not an equation, it is a formula.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: You've mentioned "one prime gives infinitely many non-primes", then I've come to wonder why doesn't it give some proof to the infinitude of Mersenne prime or Fermat prime?

Comment: It proves there are infinitely many non-prime Mersenne numbers. Not sure how it would prove infinitely many Mersenne primes. @user281

Comment: @Thomas Andrew: Oh yeah, formula sounds much better. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Thomas Andrew: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime  I don't know how to do hyperlink on comments so I just attach the link. Please Ctrl+F 'are composite' then you would find reading 'It is also not known whether infinitely many Mersenne numbers with prime exponents are composite', are they wrong? Or am I missing something?

Comment: There does exist, remarkably, an integer polynomial $f(x,y_1,\dots,y_n)$ such that, for any integer $x,$ there exists an integer solution $y_1,\dots,y_n$ to the diophantine equatioj $f(x,y_1,\dots,y_n)=0$ if and only if $x$ is prime. But that is a real equation, rather than a formula, since knowing $y_1,\dots,y_n$ doesn’t determine $x.$ And proving it is hard.

Comment: My exponents are never prime. If $p=2^q-1,$ then my result shows that $2^{q+k(2^q-2)}-1$ is always divisible by $p.$ But $2^q-2$ is divisible by $q,$ so that exponent is always divisible by $q.$

Comment: @Thomas Andrew: Now I understand. The Wikipedia statement is pointing out 'Mersenne numbers with prime exponents' which is connected to the notorious problem. Yours one are not limited to dealing with the prime exponents. So they don't contradict each other.

Comment: @Thomas Andrew: However I still wonder is  your argument sufficient to prove any of my questions of 1. and 2.?

Comment: Sorry for making the comments long. I've confused some of the statements made by Thomas. I've read it as "one prime gives infinitely many primes" which led me to some long reply of comments.

Comment: @lulu Oh, your answer was sufficient to answer the first question. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some comments which are too long to fit in a comment:

Your question is about expressions of the form $a^n+b$, but your example $72 \times 10^n-1$ is not of this form. Rather, it has the form $ca^n+b$ with $c=72$, $a=10$ and $b=-1$. This can make a difference when searching for longer stretches of values of such expressions which are prime.

There's no reason to expect that **four** consecutive prime values are the global maximum. Indeed, a quick search reveals that $72 \times 10^n-833$ is prime for $n=2,3,4,5,6$. Even better, $7 \times 10^n-927$ is prime for $n=3,4,\ldots,11$. That's $9$ consecutive prime values.

If you really prefer expressions of the form $a^n+b$, without the $c$ coefficient, you can go with $10^n-93$ which is prime for $n=2,3,\ldots,7$, or $2^n+165$ which is prime for $n=3,4,\ldots,9$.

Comment: I've seen your answers on Quora being very helpful to me. Thanks for sharing your knowledge here and there!